# “lower the amount” vs. “lower how many”

Tags: sentence-meaning, quantifiers

I need to lower **the amount of cigarettes I smoke per day.**

I need to lower **how many cigarettes i smoke per day.**

Do both the sentences mean the same thing?
Is the second one grammatically correct?

Comment: What is your specific language related question? Just comparing phrases is proofreading.

Comment: @user3169: It's not proofreading if they're focusing on a particular point that's identified by e.g. being the only point of difference. Here, "the amount" vs "how many" is very obviously being asked about. That's a valid question.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sure, but even given "the amount" vs "how many", any research regarding the meaning before asking if they are the same? Even checking a dictionary?

Comment: @user3169: You could maybe argue Details Please, but proofreading is an annoying red herring. But really, it can be answered reasonably as is, so if you don't like the lack of research, just downvote.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "Do both the sentences mean the same thing?" Yes. "Is the second one grammatically correct?" Yes (other than the "i" anyway). Problem solved. And, asking whether an example is grammatically correct alone is proofreading.

Comment: @user3169: Asking whether *a particular feature* of a sentence is grammatical [is not proofreading](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/stop-throwing-proofreading-close-reason-at-questions-that-are-clearly-limited).

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences are understandable and grammatically correct, and they both mean the same thing, that is you feel the need to smoke fewer cigarettes.

However when doing less of *some* quantity, one would usually say

> I need to **decrease** the amount of cigarettes I smoke per day.
>   I need to **decrease** how many cigarettes I smoke per day.
>
> I need to decrease the **number** of cigarettes I smoke per day.
>   I need to decrease **how much** I smoke.
>   I need to decrease my **smoking**.
>   I need to **cut down** on my smoking.

In your example, **the amount** and **how many** is interchangeable, both mean the total quantity of cigarettes you are smoking.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain or compare what they mean (that was the question).

Comment: @user3169 +1 Funny how the simplest of things slip through sometimes.

Comment: According to the dictionary, **the amount** can be used about countables such as cigarettes, but most native speakers would prefer to use **how many** or **the number**.  It's confusing because **amount** is used about money, which ought to be countable but in English it's not- for example, we say "how much money".

Comment: Both get used for money: "What **amount** of money is enough?", "**How much** money is enough?"